# Is ASP.NET MVC on Windows Azure a sane choice for a production envirnoment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

There are quite a few blog articles describing what to do in order to get on ASP.NET MVC to run on Windows Azure. The procedure does not look too complicated, but at the same time, those articles all mention that ASP.NET MVC is not officially supported on Windows Azure. On the otherh hand, the articles I have found are quite old already ( pre March 2009)

So, I am wondering: Is / was Windows Azure simply not meant for hosting ASP.NET MVC applications as part of the concept, or is this a limitation that will disappear when they release the final version of Azure? I'd feel uneasy about hosting a production site on a plattform which is not officially supporting it...

Also, what about pricing in comparison to standard dedicated hosting? I have found [this](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/pricing/) pricing table, but I it does not mention how much CPU power a standard VM in Azure has.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These days there's nothing special required to use ASP.NET MVC in Windows Azure (except to mark the MVC assembly as "Copy Always" in VS because it's not in the GAC in the cloud).  Anecdotal evidence suggests that ASP.NET MVC represents a big portion (if not the majority) of applications being built for Windows Azure these days.

Comment: Do you know off the top of your head if the other dependencies are in the Azure "GAC"? (System.Web.Routing and System.Web.Abstractions if memory serves)

Comment: I _believe_ that yes, they are.